# The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I wanted to use both annotation mapping and xml mapping in Spring MVC. My `application-context.xml` as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="personal/account/history">accountHistoryController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="accountHistoryController" class="com.fg.banking.ib.controller.AccountHistoryController" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"></bean>
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fg.banking.ib.controller, com.fg.banking.ib.helper, com.fg.banking.corporate.controller" />
```

I am getting the following error when I try to access the url. I have configured the SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter as above.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler 
[com.fg.banking.ib.controller.AccountHistoryController@218531e6]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:1128)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:903)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
```

What to do?

Comment: start by not mixing annotation based mvc and xml-based one. If you want to use <mvc:annotation-driven/> then do so.

Answer (score 71):

This error also occurs when you define a restController but forget to define the requestMapping.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/orders") // <---- dont't forget the requestMapping
```

Answer (score 31):

This problem occurred for me when I tried to define RestController path by using in this way:

```
@RestController("/test")
public class TestController {}
```

In the above section, the meaning of this declaration is different. Here actually "/test" is defined as bean name rather than path for the controller.

After defining the path in this way it worked for me:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {}
```

Answer (score 12):

I resolved the issue. I forgot to add the `@Controller` annotation in controller class. There are fore we can use the both methods(annotation mapping & XML mapping) together in an application.

Comment: Switch to `Spring Boot` for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following as a handler mapper(Worked for me):

```
<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have implemented `Controller` in your controller classes and overrided `handleRequest` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here our controller class should extends

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class AppController extends AbstractController{ }
```

Here we need to implement the abstract method as :

```
protected modelandview handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception { return null; }
```

Comment: public class AppController implements Controller{ also works