# No adapter for handler - The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler

Tags: java, spring

I am migrating Spring 3 to Spring 4, so using below configuration:
dispatcher-servlet.xml ->

```
<beans>
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>                
                <prop key="Transaction/*.do">TransactionController</prop>
</props></property></bean>
```

Controller class ->

```
@Controller
public class TransactionController {
```

applicationContext.xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd"> 
     <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"></bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
```

On running the application I am getting below error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.controller.transaction.TransactionController@6632ab18]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:947)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
```

I also tried approaches given in [The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569303/the-dispatcherservlet-configuration-needs-to-include-a-handleradapter-that-suppo) but still encountering the issue.

Comment: That doesn't work with Spring 4 anymore (assuming you are using the latest Spring 4 version that is). The default for annotations switched to `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and the respective adapter. The older `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. Al of those are deprecated in Spring 3.2 and removed in later versions. They are still there in Spring 4 so you cold add those instead of the defaults. Also the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` should be in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml ` now it is pretty useless as that configuration is ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Can you please help with code snippet to get it working with both annotations and xml configurations. Also I need to use org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping so that we dont have to use RequestMapping on all the methods

Comment: As stated you cannot anymore... Unless you want to stop upgrading after Spring 4.3 (Spring 5 removed the deprecated classes). So although you could make it work (by registering the proper handleradapter) you won't be able to upgrade further due to the fact that it isn't supported anymore.

Comment: @kapilgupta  i am also facing the same issue, what we can do to upgrade it to spring 5

Comment: @M.Deinum i am also facing the same issue, what we can do to upgrade it to spring 5